# Watch entire object (deep watch) with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a scope `angular-resource variable / object` that represents a form data:

```
    $scope.form = {
              name: 'bob', 
              email: 'bob@bobs.com'
    }
```

There is the way I watch where my `name` variable is changed.

```
    $scope.$watch('form.name', function(newVal) {
        if(newVal) {
            alert(newVal)
        }
    });
```

What would be a way to watch if any of fileds was changed- name, email, or whatever scope.form may have?

My purpose to make my form 'save' disabled or enabled depending on that fact that user has changed something on the form.

Comment: have a look at $watchCollection http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a third parameter of `$watch()` that will make it check for object equality (deep watch).

```
  $scope.$watch('form', function(newVal) { //watch the whole object
        if(newVal) {
            alert(newVal);
        }
    }, true); //pass "true" here.
```

To further complete my answer, both of these approaches produce the same result in this case: [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/oXuhoxi/1/edit) but **`$watchCollection` is shallow and will not watch anything nested for changes.**

```
  $scope.$watch('form', function(newForm, oldForm) {
    console.log(newForm.name);
  }, true);
```

OR: **(not a deep watch)**

```
  $scope.$watchCollection('form', function(newForm, oldForm) {
    console.log(newForm.name); 
  });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `if(newVal) {`? Shouldn't the function execute only when there is a new value?

Comment: @adelriosantiago Yes, but the new value may be `undefined` for the first digest cycle. This question and my answer there is an example of this also. https://stackoverflow.com/q/25723455/1435655

Answer (score 1):

Since AngularJS 1.1.x the preferred way of watching multiple values in an array or properties of an object is $watchCollection [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

```
$scope.$watchCollection('form', function(newValues, oldValues) {
    console.log('*** Watch has been fired. ***');
    console.log('New Names :', newValues);}
);
```