# Custom filter giving "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

My custom `startFrom` filter is giving me an error.

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});

app.controller("PostCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 10;
$scope.hidePagination = true;

$scope.search = function() {
    $http.get('someurl').then(sucesscalback,errorcalback);
    function sucesscalback(response)
    {
        $scope.hidePagination = false;
        console.log("Success:");
        console.log(response.data.records);
        $scope.posts = response.data;
        $scope.numberOfPages=Math.ceil($scope.posts.records.length/$scope.pageSize); 
        alert($scope.numberOfPages);
    }
    function errorcalback(failure)
    {
        console.log("Error:");
        console.log(failure);
    }
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your filter needs to check whether or not the input exists:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Otherwise, the filter function will run and thus call `slice` on `undefined` which doesn't have a property of `slice` like an array or string does.

The reason the filter is called while there is no value is because the filter will run when Angular runs its first `$digest` cycle. You could avoid the error by adding an initial value in the controller, but it's best just to add the `if` statement to the filter.

[Here's a demo of both solutions.](http://jsbin.com/codig/1/edit) Notice there are no errors.