# How do I watch 2 variables in Angularjs where 1 is the location path?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to run a function when the location path is changed OR an object via a service is changed.  I can't see to fire the function at all.

```
    var settings = {
        value : service.cache.MY_VALUE,
        location: $location.path()
    }

    $scope.$watchCollection(function(){ return settings; }, function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log('New value detected in settings');
    });
```

Why isn't the console getting triggered when I go to a new URL or change the cached value?

Comment: Show the complete code you're working with to reproduce the issue. This question is missing any code that actually updates the values in `settings`, which leads me to believe that code doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing a variable with an object literal, any function inside that literal is invoked only once:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> var settings = {
>     value : service.cache.MY_VALUE,
>     location: $location.path()
> }
> ```

The `$location.path()` function needs to be invoked every digest cycle:

```
function settingsFn() {
    return {
        value : service.cache.MY_VALUE,
        location: $location.path()
    }
}

$scope.$watchCollection( settingsFn, function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('New value detected in settings', newValue);
});
```

By placing the object literal inside the `settingsFn` function, the `$location.path()` function is invoked each time the `settingsFn` function is invoked.

Answer (score -1):

Might be a silly question, but how are you changing those values? If you're expecting settings.value to change when your service cache changes, or settings.location to change when your path changes, it won't affect $scope.settings at all.

Otherwise, what you want is a deep watch. Use $watch instead of $watchCollection, and add `true` as the 3rd argument.
[Watch entire object (deep watch) with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277479/watch-entire-object-deep-watch-with-angularjs/20277689)